# Azure Devops Server 2019 - Powershell@2 task does not run when Start-Process cmdlet is used with -Credential option

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-server-2019

I use Azure Devops Server 2019 ( On prem). I have a YAML build pipeline where I need to execute a command (mycmd.exe) as a different user than the one running the Azure agent. I use the PowerShell@2 task  and tried the following using -Credential option of start-process

```
$runasUser = "user1@mydomain.com"
  
$password = "mypassWord"

$runasPassword = "$password"  | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$runAsCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ( $runasUser, $runasPassword )

Start-Process mycmd.exe -ArgumentList $params -Credential $runAsCredential -WorkingDirectory "$binaryPath" -NoNewWindow -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput "$binaryPath\stdOut.txt" -RedirectStandardError "$binaryPath\stdErrorOut.txt"
```

The process seems to exit without performing any task. I see the  redirects files **stdOut.txt** and **stdErrorOut.txt** are both empty.

I tried to use Wait-Process cmdlet instead of -Wait (as mentioned here [Start-Process hangs when used with -Credential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923200/start-process-hangs-when-used-with-credential) ) but that did not work either.

```
Start-Process mycmd.exe -ArgumentList $params -Credential $runAsCredential -WorkingDirectory "$binaryPath" -NoNewWindow -PassThru -RedirectStandardOutput "$binaryPath\stdOut.txt" -RedirectStandardError "$binaryPath\stdErrorOut.txt" | Wait-Process
```

I saw this post as well [Azure Pipelines: Start-Process with credentials not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71926900/azure-pipelines-start-process-with-credentials-not-working) but unfortunately I do not have the privilege of running the process as a scheduled task on the agent server

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Hi Sibi what do you mean by `task does not run`? the azure devops server `powershell task` or you `mycmd.exe`? With the reference with the doc for [start-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3) and adding `-filepath`, we managed to run our pipeline with success.

Comment: Hi Ceeno, Thank you for your response. I tried with directly executing mycmd.exe as well as powershell.exe executing mycmd.exe. In both cases, I do not see any output (either in stdOut.txt or stdErrorOut.txt) . The command however works fine if I run outside the Azure devops server Powershell@2 task within a normal powershell.

Comment: Please note I run Azure DevOps Server, Version Dev17.M153.5

Comment: I also tried   $process.WaitForExit() instead of using -Wait option or | Wait-Process. I still get the same result

Comment: I even tried running a simple bat file with "timeout /NOBREAK /T 120 >nul"  to generate a 2 minute delay but that also does not seem to execute

Comment: HI, have you tried to run the pipeline with the task [Powershell on Target Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-on-target-machines-v3?view=azure-pipelines) ?